# Объект в объекте это ссылка?

Tags: javascript

Я пометил интересующую меня строку.

**obj в obj2** это ссылка в объекте **obj2**

на объект **obj** или это скопированные данные **из obj в obj2?**

Я запутался, помогите разобраться =(

```js
let obj = {
  number: 122,
  room: 146
}

let obj2 = {
  call: "Alice",
  age: 32,
  obj, // **Метка**
}

let json = JSON.stringify(obj2, null, 2)

console.log(json);
```

Comment: ссылка. Это очень легко проверить, изменив какое-нибудь  поле в `obj`.

Comment: Cпасибо, добрый человек =)

Comment: Обычные объекты в JS ни при каких обстроятельствах сами по себе не копируются, это всегда ссылка)